# Trying to disable expired cards

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Hey guys I hope you can help me out, im maping some items with an specific prop, called expired and I want every card to render in a disabled state but I can´t figure out how, I'm using MUI components here goes my code:

```
{expired && 
   expired.map((item, i) => <CurrentSales key={item.id ?? i} item={item} />)}
</>) : null}
```

Sorry if I pasted my code all wrong I'm new in Stack, thanks!

By far I've tried adding to the component the disabled prop, but it ain't working:

```
{expired && 
   expired.map((item, i) => <CurrentSales disabled key={item.id ?? i} item={item} />)}
</>) : null}
```

I'm trying to render it in disabled state.

Comment: What does the `CurrentSales` component look like? Does it expect a "disabled" prop and pass that down to the child components?

Comment: no, I'm tryng to make the whole component to render in a disabled state, the child component is a simple MUI card component with the item prop being displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CurrentSales` custom component must accept the "disabled" prop and adjust the styling accordingly. The MUI card also does not accept a "disabled" prop either according to [the docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/card/). "disabled" is unfortunately not a native prop that can be passed to any React component to achieve a faded non-interactive element.

In your custom component, you will have to apply an optional style to the component when the "disabled" prop is true that desaturates the colors and sets mouse events to none.

```css
/* the lazy way */
.disabled {
  opacity: 0.6; /* change appearance */
  pointer-events: none; /* disable interactivity */
  cursor: not-allowed; /* optionally change cursor */
}

/* the careful way */
.disabled {
  color: #...; /* lower saturation of theme colors */
  background-color: #...; /* lower saturation of theme colors */
  pointer-events: none; /* disable interactivity */
  cursor: not-allowed; /* optionally change cursor */
}
```